# Biconvex lenses in 2 media

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

The question is what is the formula of the focal length of a biconvex thin lens if object medium is water and the image medium is air.

I know that we have: 1/f = (n-1)*(1/R1 - 1/R2) , if the medium around lens is air, but i don't know the exact formula if there is another medium.

I derived something like this: 
n/f = (n-n2)/R2 + (n2-n1)/R1; where n is refractive index in water, n1: in air and n2 in glass. R1 is the radius of the lens in water and R2 the radius of the lens in air. But i don't know if it is true.